# MSSQL query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I want to run MSSQL query in CodeIgniter framework but it is throwing error like:

```
Error Number: 42S22/207

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '1'.

SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE id ="1"
```

I'm trying to run following query:

```
SELECT id,fname,lname,username,email FROM user_master WHERE username ="admin" AND password ="123456"
```

when this same query into MSSQL, it works with a single quotation ('). But when I'm passing variables in the query then it is automatically assigned double quotation.

Suggest some solution.

Comment: Show the code where you're building the query string.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/uaKJeNM4dTV743DBcVq7AH 
here is the code.

Comment: You could probably get it to work by setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER off, but that doesn't seem like the correct solution.

Comment: Have you tried active record??

Comment: You should check this documentation.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue a while ago
I tried turning on query builder in database.php

```
$query_builder = TRUE;
```

there might be issue with IIS server cache. Clear cache and try.

I hope this will work

Comment: yes, I've tried.it's working. (my query builder is off in database.)
thanks, you save my day.